# Spring MVC and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a **Spring Mvc** application and i want when the user clicks on the submit button and is returned to the view that a **jquery dialog** be displayed like '*Transaction was successful*' or an error message if any in a dialog.

Presently when the form reaches the controller once processing is done if the transaction is successful or any errors i set **model.addAttribute('ServerResponse', 'Transaction Was successful')** or **model.addAttribute('ServerResponse',e)**.

I would like to return '**ServerResponse**' into the dialog however i dont know what is the best event to attach the **jquery** to. I don't want to create a web service since i am already using a post to the server and in the event **javascript** is turned off.

Can someone tell me whats the best way to show the dialog with the ServerResponse once the ServerResponse element has a value. Initially when the form is loaded ServerResponse should be empty.

Hope i was clear enough on what i am trying to achieve here.

**Edited**

This is what i am doing but the function is not executing when i return form the server its actually displaying at the point where the div was created.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Server Response">
            <p>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
                ${results}
            </p>

        </div>

 $(function() {

         var serverResponse = $('#serverResponse').val().length;

            alert(serverResponse);

         if(serverResponse != 0){

             alert(serverResponse);
             $("#dialog").dialog();              
         }

      });
```

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing the concepts of using jQuery for AJAX and traditional full Request style MVC.  Are you looking to return a new View with the dialog present?  Are you using a "redirect:/" to prevent double submission?  If JavaScript is turned off the jQuery dialog won't work either, so that line of thought doesn't seem to make sense, and it sounds like you should be using a Web service if you want to go that route and create a controller method that returns something like a `ResponseEntity<String>` (or something more meaningful) which can be grabbed by the front end.

Comment: If you _do_ really want to go that route you should be able to output the model data using whatever template system you're using into a div which is then popped up using jQuery dialog on document ready.

Comment: yes i am returning a new view. Its a simple form submission. I am not using a "redirect:/". I know when javascript is turned off Jquery wont work either so basically i am not relying on any JavaScript, JQuery or WebService for form submission. Basically i am using a form submit and i would like when i return form the server to show a JQuery dialog with some message from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output the message from the model into a div using whatever template language you're using in your view layer.  Something like:

```
<div id="serverResponse"><%= serverResponse %></div>
```

Style accordingly and then in jquery (with jquery UI) on that page do:

```
$(function() {
  $("#serverResponse").dialog();
}
```

And then do whatever styling you want.  The plain div will display if there's no javascript or will be pulled in to the dialog if there is.  You could use a `noscript` and duplicated content to eliminate the momentary flash of content before its pulled into the dialog.

Comment: I updated my code i am having some issues when i load the form i am seeing the icon showing in the location where it was written and when i submit to the server and return the dialog doesn't come up but the results is displayed on the form not in a dialog